# What are the possible grants/stipends/scholarships that are available in the Republic of Austria?

Tags: graduate-school, funding, tuition

Yesterday I was offered to join Central European University (now situated in Vienna, Austria). The dream came true, and I was invited to get a MPA degree.

CEU Admissions Committee gave me a very generous tuition discount (more than 70%), but I still cannot afford this. It's too expensive for me and my home country - >3000 euro. I could afford this offer in case of selling all my properties. Obviously, I will not do it.

What are the possible ways to find additional financial support? What scholarships or grants options are available for Austria? What are the most suitable and reliable ways of receiving a funding for the non-EU resident?

Comment: Why not to ask CEU?

Comment: Alchemista is right - the first point of contact for possible funding possibilities is the university you applied to. This is especially so in this case because that university is a private one, which possibly reduces the number of funding opportunities. They should, at the very least, have an overview of scholarships you can apply for. Sometimes universities have their own scholarship programs as well.

Comment: I'll take a stab at an answer later. For the moment, please google "Studienbeihilfe". BTW, what's your nationality? Are you an EU citizen?

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica According to the [OP's profile](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/135185/k1rgas), their location is Moscow, Россия.

Comment: @Alchimista it goes without saying that you are right. But today is Saturday which means that admissions office will not respond. I still have a nervous trembling after getting an offer. I want to find all possible opportunities as soon as possible because the offer respond deadline is in a week.

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica okay, thank you! I'll try to check this out.

Comment: Major point is the private character of that fundation.

Answer (score 1):

Austria has an official agency for International students, called the OeAD, which, in turn, offers a database of possible funding sources for academic purposes at https://grants.at

Grants.at allows for a granular search. You can select your nationality, state that you are an incoming student, and choose the option of funding of a full study programme.

Here is an example screenshot if you are from Russia:

[image: Grants.at screenshot of a granular search]

Good luck (and congratulations on getting accepted at the CEU)!

Comment: Thank you, I will contact some of the funding organisations.